# WSL seems to not exist anymore after switch to Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL on my computer for programming, but for a few months I haven't really been using it, instead using Jupyter notebooks in the cloud.

Today, I was going to go back to using it, but my VSCode extension can't find WSL. In fact, the WSL extension just doesn't work. Upon further inspection, I saw that the command `wsl` wouldn't return anything, and instead would freeze without outputting any info.

I believe this might be because when I was using WSL, I had Windows 10, but now have Windows 11.

So what do I do now? Should I delete and reinstall WSL? Is there some other voodoo magic way?

Comment: Can you confirm Windows Subsystem for Linux is currently installed on your system?

Comment: How about `wsl --help` or `wsl -l -v`?  Do those return or hang?

Comment: @Ramhound I can confirm that. Using `Restart-Service` to try and restart WSL says it does exist, and `wsl.exe` exists on my computer

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `wsl --help` works as intended. `wsl -l -v` hangs.

Comment: @Arandomcoder - The fact wsl.exe exists doesn’t confirm the feature is installed. Can you provide a screenshot showing the feature is installed. Also verify that VT-x or AMDs equivalent is also enabled

Comment: @Arandomcoder You can also check the feature status from an Admin PowerShell with `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"`.  If you'd like to include the results here (in the question), just pipe it to `| clip.exe` for easy copy/paste.  Also might be interesting to see what `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName "VirtualMachinePlatform"` shows.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  

`FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux
                   shells and tools on Windows`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds getting VirtualMachinePlatform returns it being enabled, but "RestartRequired" is listed as possible

Comment: @Arandomcoder That all sounds normal.  The `Possible` just means that future upgrades might require a restart.  But both seem to be installed and enabled.

Comment: Try to uninstall WSL, reboot, install, reboot. This is done is *Settings > Apps > Optional features*, and the options are "Virtual Machine Platform" and “Windows Subsystem for Linux”. Backup your distributions before starting.

Comment: Since you are on Windows 11, I just had a thought.  Try installing the WSL Preview from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  It (a) hopefully will replace the existing WSL that's being problematic for you (it's designed to "override" the "stock" WSL), and (b) it's designed to provide some better error messages when there's a problem.

Comment: But I do also agree with @harrymc.  If you haven't done it yet, it's certainly worth a try to reinstall.  If you need help backing up the distros first, let me know as well.

Comment: A reinstall worked, but I'm still curious why WSL froze like that @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: Is the problem fixed now after the reinstall?

Comment: @Arandomcoder We'll probably never know for sure.  Sometimes, things get into a bad state -- It could have happened somehow before the Windows 11 upgrade or perhaps during.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem apparently was fixed by reinstalling WSL.

This is done in *Settings > Apps > Optional features*,
where the options to turn off and on are "Virtual Machine Platform"
and "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

The actions to do are : Disable both options, reboot, enable the options,
reboot.

This solved the poster's problem, but also erased any evidence of what
went wrong (but it's not sure that could have been tracked down).

Comment: Before that I would search system drive for Linux files and backup what I need. They are deep in folders but in plain format. If upgrade to Windows 11 didn't removed them.